# Bitbake - layer version?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

Is there a semblance of a "layer version" in bitbake, or a way to impose such a variable to auto-increment anytime a recipe in that layer changes? I would like to take this meta-data and embed it in an environment variable in the image so I can map a deployed image to a git commit for my layer

Comment: Since the layer doesn't change, and isn't an entity that is trackable, what you want to do is track individual commits in that layer, correct? Use the following in your recipes, which will identify the built version.

`SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
PV .= "+git${SRCPV}"`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right - track individual commits. I wonder, would the above also track .bbappends, for example if the base recipe does not change, but only the .bbappend does, would that still be tracked?

Comment: You would need to add a PN maybe? I don't know how that would work exactly. Then manually bump the PN every time you make a change somehow?